# How to implement hellban in Firebase chat?

Tags: firebase

I am developing a chat using a Firebase. But I have a problem with implementing a hellban. I need the next functionality:
- If user is hellbanned he can write messages and he can see and read it, but other users should not see these messages.
I don't have a right solution of this problem. Have you an api for implementing of this hellban functionality? Or may be you can take me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your requirements.

If you want *all* messages by the hell-banned user to be banned (that includes messages sent *before* and *after* the ban), then you should create a `banned` boolean property on the *user* object and set it to `true`. Figuring out if a message should be shown to another user is then just a matter of checking if the 'banned' flag is set on the violator's user object in the "on-new-message" handler.

If you want to take the route of having individual messages flagged (in cases when you just want to the block messages sent *after* the user gets banned), then you should also set the flag on the `message` object in addition to setting the flag on the violator's `user` object. Before you write out a new message check if the writer of the message has been banned, and if she is then set the `banned` flag on the message to true. In your "on-new-message" handler check if the `banned` flag is set before displaying it to the user.

In either case you should also check the userId on the message that goes to the "on-new-message" and display it regardless of the `banned` status if it was written by the logged-in user.

Some examples to guide you through (in JavaScript):

```
/* ref is on messages collection */

//Retrieval
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
  var newMessage = snapshot.val();
  if(newMessage.userId == user.id || !newMessage.banned) {
    /* Display Message */
  }
});

//Posting
var newMessage = {
    userId = user.id
    ...
}
if(user.banned){
    newMessage.banned = true;
}
ref.push(newMessage)
```